# Retrieve a custom module collection within a Static Block

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, module, static-block

Built a very simple custom module, name, description and image.

I want to display all custom mod items on a static block, any ideas of the process?

I want to then attach the static block to a category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I may have been looking for:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="folder/template.phtml"}}
```